# How I use for loop to get the addition result?

Tags: php, loops, math, for-loop

My math query is (1+5+
10+15+20+25 =?)

How I use for loop to get the addition result?

Comment: form where this number came? are you want to generate it dynamically?

Comment: have you tried anything yet

Comment: Yes I will give dynamically. Have you any idea for solving ?

Comment: `echo 1+5+ 10+15+20+25;` your welcome

Comment: Don't bother, it will be 76!!

Comment: ah yes then you can do `echo "76"` is this correct syntax for php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  $answer = 1;

  for($x=1;$x<6;$x++){
      $answer+=5*$x;
  }

  echo $answer;
```

Comment: did you run that. run it and check

Comment: pseudo code. there, its perfectly good pseudo code

Comment: now you corrected it. good